# Branch merge from svn without merging automatically

Tags: svn, merge

I am using Tortoise SVN and came across the FAQ answer on the Tortoise SVN website about disabling automatic merges when updating your working copy. This solution works fine for updating but I would like to disable automatic merging when merging branch changes to a working copy. I tried modifying the config file so that I have these three lines now :

```
diff-cmd = "C:\\false.bat"
diff3-cmd = "C:\\false.bat"
merge-tool-cmd = "C:\\false.bat"
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. Is there a way to disable automatic merge for the merge command just like it works for the update command?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what the intent is here. So you have a file that's in a branch, and you want to merge it into the trunk I assume. You run the `svn merge` command, however you don't want it to merge? What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I want it to merge unchanged files automatically but if files have changed, I'd like to manually merge those files using my merge tool to make sure everything merges properly.